# Android listview loaded with DB is very slow

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a not very big truth database, create a class for the listview adapter where I show an image and a string that is the name of a person. My problem is that loads very slow, it takes around 2 to 5 minutes to load 5 records in other cases the database can have up to 1000 data and that would be very problematic. I leave the classes and how they load to see if I can help or if some other element to replace it.

```
public void cargarListView(){
    nueva = new database();
    SessionManager manager = new SessionManager();
    codigoEvento = manager.getValue(this,"codigoEvento");
    codigoUser = manager.getValue(this, "codigoUser");
    idInscripcionesDisponibles = nueva.inscripcionesEvento(this, codigoEvento);
    inscripcionesDisponibles = new String[idInscripcionesDisponibles.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < idInscripcionesDisponibles.length; i++) {
        if (manager.getValue(listasAsistentes.this, "checkin")!=null){
            codigo_checkin = nueva.codigoCheckin(listasAsistentes.this, manager.getValue(listasAsistentes.this, "checkin"));
            if(nueva.checkinValidado(listasAsistentes.this,  idInscripcionesDisponibles[i], codigo_checkin)>0){
                inscripcionesDisponibles[i] = nueva.nombreInscripcion(this, idInscripcionesDisponibles[i], codigoEvento);
                RowItem item = new RowItem(images[0], inscripcionesDisponibles[i],Integer.parseInt(idInscripcionesDisponibles[i]));
                rowItems.add(item);
            }else{
                inscripcionesDisponibles[i] = nueva.nombreInscripcion(this, idInscripcionesDisponibles[i], codigoEvento);
                RowItem item = new RowItem(images[1], inscripcionesDisponibles[i],Integer.parseInt(idInscripcionesDisponibles[i]));
                rowItems.add(item);
            }
        }else{
            if(nueva.validadoInscripcion(listasAsistentes.this, idInscripcionesDisponibles[i], codigoEvento).equals("1")){
                inscripcionesDisponibles[i] = nueva.nombreInscripcion(this, idInscripcionesDisponibles[i], codigoEvento);
                RowItem item = new RowItem(images[0], inscripcionesDisponibles[i],Integer.parseInt(idInscripcionesDisponibles[i]));
                rowItems.add(item);
            }else{
                inscripcionesDisponibles[i] = nueva.nombreInscripcion(this, idInscripcionesDisponibles[i], codigoEvento);
                RowItem item = new RowItem(images[1], inscripcionesDisponibles[i],Integer.parseInt(idInscripcionesDisponibles[i]));
                rowItems.add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}




public void cargarLista(){
    nueva = new database();
    SessionManager manager = new SessionManager();
    codigoEvento = manager.getValue(this,"codigoEvento");

    codigoUser = manager.getValue(this, "codigoUser");
    checkin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    nombreEventoTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    sincronizarBD= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    nombreEvento = manager.getValue(this, "nombreEvento");
    nombreEventoTxt.setText(nombreEvento);
    if (manager.getValue(listasAsistentes.this, "checkin")!=null){
        checkin.setText("Check-In: "+nueva.nombreCheckin(listasAsistentes.this, manager.getValue(listasAsistentes.this, "checkin")));
    }else{
        checkin.setText("Check-In: General");
    }
    System.out.println("ITEMS : "+rowItems.size());
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    if(rowItems.size() <1){
        sincronizarBD.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        inputSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
        noHayAsistentes = new TextView(listasAsistentes.this); 
        noHayAsistentes.setText("No existen asistentes descargados, por favor sincronizar.");
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.topMargin = 300;
        params.leftMargin = 10;
        noHayAsistentes.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        noHayAsistentes.setTextSize((float) 14);
        noHayAsistentes.setLayoutParams(params);
        rl.addView(noHayAsistentes);
    }else{
        inputSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,R.layout.lista, rowItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                cs = cs.toString().toLowerCase();
                cs = cs.toString().replace ('á','a');
                cs = cs.toString().replace ('é','e');
                cs = cs.toString().replace ('í','i');
                cs = cs.toString().replace ('ó','o');
                cs = cs.toString().replace ('ú','u');
                listasAsistentes.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString().trim());   
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });
        adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
                R.layout.lista, rowItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                listasAsistentes.this.adapter.getItem(position);
                System.out.println("ID ITEM:"+listasAsistentes.this.adapter.getItem(position).getInscripcionId());
                SessionManager manager = new SessionManager();
                //String idSeleccionada = idInscripcionesDisponibles[position];
                manager.setValue(listasAsistentes.this,"idInscripcionSeleccionada", String.valueOf(listasAsistentes.this.adapter.getItem(position).getInscripcionId()));
                nueva.inscripcionSeleccionada(listasAsistentes.this, String.valueOf(listasAsistentes.this.adapter.getItem(position).getInscripcionId()));
                menu();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess that you didn't **INDEX** your fields properly.

At least those fields which are part of **JOIN** s and those which are part of **WHERE** conditions must be indexed.

You'll get a noticeable performance boost, up to **100s** times faster (I hade a speed increase of about **350x**, determined empyrically).

To see how to index a field, I suggest you this very nice tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_indexes.htm

In poor words (an extremely synthetic excerpt from that tutorial),
add these instructions after your table creation:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name (column_name);
```

for each index you want to create

By using the `IF NOT EXISTS` construct you'll avoid recreating indexes, if already existing.

i.e.:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idxID ON your_table_name (_id);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idxSearch ON your_table_name (a_field_used_in_searches);
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? I had no idea what he says! and thanks for your response

Comment: Very good tutorial entiendi fine but it remains a question, as I access aa check whether or not wearing a certain index?

Comment: Then to make the sql query to filter my data, I can see "WHERE index = X value"? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No, indexes will be **invisible** to you. Let's call it a database **optimization**. You'll still use "WHERE my_field = my_value"

Comment: Thanks I had no idea of this, as it proves, friend apology, a way to communicate if you need help? Greetings!

Comment: Well, nobody borns "already learned". There are so many thing I still have to discover... and I'm aged!